# Yahoo finance.yahoo.com/quotes is redirecting

Tags: yahoo-finance

I use https://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/... for stock quotes and option data.  It continues to work well when viewed in a Safari browser.  I also take it in to an Objective C app as an NSURLSession dataTaskWithUrL.  Last week (circa April 28, 2017)it started forcing a redirect by calling willPerformHTTPRedirection: but the redirect loops to itself and generates the "too many HTTP redirects" error.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838109/how-to-download-data-from-web-using-tr-and-td-tag-names

Answer (score 0):

I found that, Yahoo Finance changed their website address format from (4/1) "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL&g=w"
to (4/8) "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?interval=1wk"

Then, on 4/21, the weekly historical data imported differently, excluding some advertisements lines between the stock symbol & pricing to "Date / Open ... Adjusted Close" heading along with the number of columns from date to volume.

On 5/5, Yahoo Finance Historical data would not open via the VBA programming.  Other financial sites like MSN, Google, Market Watch, & Invetopedia continue to open using the same VBA code.

Finally, when I paste the newer Yahoo link listed above into a spreadsheet and then click on the link, the webpage is redirected to Apple's general Summary site, not the Historical Data tab.

Will try a few other lines of code, but after that, will look at changing to Investopedia.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I finally came up with:

In the original NSURLRequest, make it an NSURLMutableRequest and add:

```
[theRequest setValue:@"Mozilla......." forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

This 'spoofing the browser' often works with no redirects.  But sometimes there is a redirect.  Therefore I also added the method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)redirectResponse newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler{
```

and in the completion handler I examine the task.currentRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:, set it to a different browser and generate a new NSURLRequest with the different browser.  It seems to be working.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the work of 2 other people I seem to have a solution to this problem.  Actually there are 2 aspects to the issue of downloading historic data from Yahoo:

1. The redirection issue
2. Establishing a working cookie/crumb combination.

The solution which enables me to continue using my Excel spreadsheets and the associated VBA code is based on:

- The work of Dennis Lee who demonstrates how to extract the cookie / crumb combination https://github.com/dennislwy/YahooFinanceAPI.
- The work of Tim Hall who has written VBA-Web
  https://vba-tools.github.io/VBA-Web/docs/#/WebClient/GetFullUrl

Comment: The question asks how one may solve a redirect issue, causing an issue for an app written in ObjectiveC. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Excel/VBA, nor to either of the links you've posted. If the code that illustrates how to solve the redirect issue is buried in the github repo in the first link, please extract it and discuss how it does so.

Comment: I am sorry you don't think my contribution has any value.  However, a lot of issues have been raised about the changes to the Yahoo Finance website which have broken many peoples' download routines but I have not seen anyone provide a solution in any software environment.  In my case VBA-Web overcame the problems of redirection when I was using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.  As no one else had proposed any sort of solution on this thread I thought that this was a positive contribution which would provide some food for thought.  Perhaps you have a better idea.